# Where is the steam directory folder in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, directory, steam

I've checked in the home folder but this is all I see.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steam applications are stored in `~/.local/share/Steam` by default. To make the .local folder visible in nautilus hit `Ctrl + h` and all hidden folders will be revealed. It is also possible to change the Steam install location using a configuration within the Steam program.

Comment: Glad I could help. Just so you know, "Thank You" posts are discouraged on this site since we already have votes and you can mark the answer as the correct answer.  If you want to say thank you just upvote the post or mark it as the answer. Welcome to the community.